# Transforming List<T> into Map<T.Prop, List<T>> using the streams API

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Consider that `T` is the `Group` class and `S` is the `Option` class.

I have the following code:

```
public static class Group {
    List<Option> options;

    public List<Option> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(List<Option> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public Group(List<Option> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}

public static class Option {
    int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Option(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Option option1 = new Option(1);
    final Option option2 = new Option(2);
    final Option option3 = new Option(3);
    final Option option4 = new Option(4);
    final Option option5 = new Option(5);
    final Option option6 = new Option(6);
    final Group group1 = new Group(Arrays.asList(option1, option2));
    final Group group2 = new Group(Arrays.asList(option3, option4, option5, option6));        
}
```

I want to create Map where optionId would be a key and group would be a value

thus it should be

```
1 - group1
2 - group1
3 - group2
4 - group2
5 - group2
6 - group2
```

Does stream api allow to resolve this task?

Comment: Are those examples right, or are 3-6 meant to be 2, my answer is based on the assumption the examples are wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
Stream.of(group1, group2)
    .flatMap(p -> p.getOptions().stream().map(q -> new Pair<>(p,q)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        p -> p.getValue().getId(), 
        p -> p.getKey()));
```

- First it gets the groups
- Then it pairs the options with them
- Then it puts them into a map

Pair in this example is `javafx.util.Pair`, although others can be used in its place if prefered.

Comment: What is Pair class?

Comment: you should consider renaming the stream variables. Instead of `p` and `q`, names such as `group` `option` or `pair` are much more readable.

Comment: @gstackoverflow i think he's referencing the [Apache Commons Pair-Class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)

Comment: Pair is `javafx.util.Pair`, as JavaFX is included with the JRE it doesn't add any dependencies, I used a single letter for the lambda arguments, but that is a matter of style, I can change it

Answer (score 0):

Try following, but I assume your output 3-6 meant to be group2.

```
    final Map<Number,String> m = new HashMap<>();
    group1.getOptions().stream().forEach(p -> {m.put(p.getId(), "group1");});
    group2.getOptions().stream().forEach(p -> {m.put(p.getId(), "group2");});
    System.out.println(m);
```